# Having issues with CSS on mobile displaying background image in portrait format

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I am relatively new to programming and trying to get a background image to display on mobile.  It seems to work OK on mobile landscape but not on mobile portrait.  It displays about a 1/3 of the image in portrait.  I have tried height: 100% width: 100%, background-position: center, background-size: cover.  I also tried to create another image 290px in width and then use media queries to call that image.  Neither of these things have worked.  Any help to get this solved would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Please provide us with a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem so that we can see the code and help you trouble shoot the issue.

Comment: It is basically a landing page, and no problem!  I have alot of learning to do!  www.patonplacetestsite3.ca

Answer (score 1):

Here's another suggestion for you.

What you are trying to do isn't easy because you're wanting your design to work on all viewports or screensizes, and at the same time, you have some text info that should always be visible.

Here's one suggestion for you:
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/Lmjwyv

The important bits are:

(1) You want to add a viewport meta tag in the head of your document, this will stop smartphones from scaling content to fit the screen

```
<head>  
...  
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
...
</head>
```

[More about viewport meta tags here](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/responsive-html/viewport-meta-element/)

(2) Change the positioning of your background image to left bottom, then the critical text will remain in view at different viewports

```
background-image: url(images/ComingSoon.jpg);
...
 background-position:left bottom;  
...  
}
```

(3) Building on what you started, create a second portrait format background image for mobile, then use a media query to show it below whatever viewport works best for your design

```
@media  screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Small screen, non-retina */
 .bgimg { 
   background-image:    url(images/ComingSoon_Small_Portrait.jpg); 
       background-size: contain;
  } 
}
```

[Here's an example of what I'm thinking of](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/QBBSgpjJKefF6rPH4cMyG-CuuqOetuRJ9vdGwv9fawCruPuR0sMHKpUF0gOwHubejFFoL0EinShamDrKsuKNBoNx6a1cqONK3USpQiCp38PRDmCDHfRH5QKgQ6M1XOH-2aMJtOCigA=s250-k-no)

Background size wouldn't necessarily need to be 'contain', I'm just illustrating that it could be different from the setting for desktop.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you that's an interesting way of doing it.  Just one question what dimensions would you suggest for small screen? right now I have one set as 290px X 163px.

Comment: I would start by looking at your desktop view, then reduce the window width until you don't like how the background image fits on the page. For argument sake, let's say this is at 600px wide. Assuming that a typical aspect ration of a smartphone screen is very approximately 1 wide x 2 high, you could create a portrait format background image that was 600px wide x 1200px high, and the media query would be as in my example ... (max-width: 600px). There's nothing to stop you from having smartphone, tablet and desktop background images if you wanted to. Base everything on your background design.

Comment: I basically have the desktop version OK, and landscape on Mobile but the portrait version on Mobile still having problems with.  If anyone has any further comments I would appreciate it!

Comment: Have you considered placing the text either above or below the image for the mobile portrait version?

Comment: I moved the text "ie. timer" above the image.  The Omnia Dance Coming Soon is part of the image.  Still have the issue with the image in portrait on mobile.  https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=EUamoJZQLBs-rImFhBOZpg

Comment: Please see my edit to (3) above for an example of what I was thinking of.

Comment: I see what you mean now.  Change the image itself I.e text above the graphic so that it would fit in portrait a better.  That's what I am trying to do is change that image design so the image would fit better in portrait format.  If thats what you mean I will let you know how I make out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly!

Comment: The only issue I have is the one I am using now as the small image is 290px X 163px.  I appreciate it would not fit the whole screen but it should fit the width in portrait right?  But it doesn't fit at all.  I will still go ahead with my above comment but if you can give me some input on that part it would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, 290 x 163 is a bit small. Is there any reason why you can't make a larger version, at least 450px wide x 750px high?

Comment: No there is no reason.  My point is it should fit widthwise now and its not even close.  I will do that but from what I read they say the ideal width is 340 px X whatever.  Can you tell me why the image is not fitting widthwise presently? You can see here:  https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=xq1kQRHh212nbco7T2BYww

Comment: At line 54 or your CSS, increase the max-width to at least 414px, I believe this is the width of an iPhone 7/8 s

Comment: Your right on the money! Thank you!  I will look now at re-doing the image to 340px X 700 px roughly.  Really appreciate all your help!!

Comment: Back again!  So took me a bit to re do the image.  It generally works on portrait mobile now but doesn't fit my Galaxy 7 completely.  Would you suggest something in CSS or just change with the width of the image.  Currently at 340 px X 688 px.  Appreciate any comments to resolve my last issue.  View here:  https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?id=Vn_CvIHJaC_rhNsAJ4YNMg

Comment: Ignore my last comment didn't refresh enough.  Moved to proper location and looks fine at www.omniadance.ca  Thanks again!

Comment: Good to hear @PatonPlace

Answer (score 0):

What is the intended behavior?

**`background-size: contain;`**

> Scales the image as large as possible without cropping or stretching the image.

**`background-size: cover;`**

> Scales the image as large as possible without stretching the image. If the proportions of the image differ from the element, it is cropped either vertically or horizontally so that no empty space remains.

(from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

If you want to show the whole image, without cropping, you need to use `background-size: contain;`. The image will then no longer fill the whole background in portrait mode, and you probably want to add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` as well.

Comment: Thank you!  Its a little better, I would have to adjust the CSS on the timer obviously.  The downside of course is the background does not cover the full background on the desktop.